# Absolute positioning and percentage height

Tags: html, css, height, css-position

Please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/A2Qnx/1/

```
<div id='w'>
   <div id='p'>
       <div id='c'>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When absolute positioning is on, div P has a height of 60px (50 from parent + 10 from padding).

Now if you turn absolute positioning off, both div P and div W will have the same height of 110px (100 from child + 10 from padding).

Can someone explain to me what happened here?

1) When absolute positioning is on, why does P take its 100% height from the min-height of the parent instead of the height of the children? (and why is padding only applied to P?)

2) When absolute positioning is off, why does P take its 100% height from the children instead of min-height of the parent? (and why is padding only applied to P AND W?)

Answer (score 0):

Padding is only styled on `#p`...

As for the height, absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal flow. Height o 100% makes that element take on the full height of any parent with position other than static (or the body if none were found). As it is not in the flow, the `#w` element effectively has no elements in it, hence why it reverts back to its min-height.